# What's the difference between the main types of logic?

Tags: logic, definition, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, boolean-algebra

I've heard of all sorts of logic: Mathematical logic, propositional logic, first order logic, second order logic, predicate logic, Boolean logic / algebra, etc.

What are the main differences between these categories and how do I know what to apply when?

Comment: All fall under the topic : Mathematical logic. See [Propositional Logic](https://www.iep.utm.edu/prop-log/) and [Predicate logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic). In predicate logic we may have predicate of different "levels" : the simplest one is *First-order logic* where quantification is allowed only on individual variables and **not** on predicate ones. See also [Boolean algebra](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boolalg-math/).

Comment: Related : [Is First Order Logic (FOL) the only fundamental logic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176263/is-first-order-logic-fol-the-only-fundamental-logic)

Comment: Also related : [What is mathematical logic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993596/what-is-mathematical-logic)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Predicate logic describes both first and second order logic? And first order has you quantifying variables, but second order has you quantifying predicates? Aren't predicates also quantifiers?

Comment: Yes; predicate logic has predicate variables. In FOL we cannot quantify over predicates; in SOL we can quantify on them; and so on. And no, predicates are not quantifiers.

Comment: See also [What is a formal definition of predicate logic ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687238/what-is-a-formal-definition-of-predicate-logic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a very good answer would require probably to read a good book in mathematical logic.

Nevertheless here is a very short, and possibly rough, description of the terms you asked for. Be careful, what follows is a very imprecise description of the various kind of logic, but again I think this is the best one can get in the limit of a post (or at least, that is the best I can think of).

Mathematical logic denote that branch of mathematics that applies the technique of mathematics to the study of logics. It basically provides formal ways to define what a logical system is and how to prove stuff about these systems.

Propositional, first-order and second order logics are just few examples of these *formal logical systems*.

The differences in these systems are in the expressiveness of the said systems.

For instance in propositional logic one deals only with true-or-false statements while in first-order logic one can use formulas which states that certain relations hold for *some objects* or for *all the objects*.

In second-order logic we can start to state that *relations between relations* hold for certain relations or for all the possible relations, something which cannot be done in first-order logic.

The term Boolean logic is usually used a synonym for propositional logic.

Boolean algebra is a term used for denote a certain class of algebraic structure which captures the algebraic properties of propositional logic.

**Edit**: by the way if you look at wikipedia's article you can find lots of informations on the subjects.

**Edit 2**: the OP asked in the comments below for an example of second order sentence, here is an informal example.

In what follow I will use the following notation: 
$P x$ will mean $x$ satisfies the property (unary relation) $P$ and $x R y$ will mean $x$ is in the relation $R$ with $y$.

For every binary relation $R$ such that

- for all $x$ we have that $x R x$
- forall $x$ and $y$ if $x R y$ and $y R x$ then $x=y$
- forall $x$, $y$ and $z$ if $x R y$ and $y R z$ then $x R z$
- forall properties $P$ such that exists at least an $x$ for which $P x$ there is a $m$ such that $P m$ holds and for every other $x$ for which $Px$ holds we have $m R x$

we have that forall $x$ and $y$ either $x R y$ or $y R x$.

This apparently complex statement is basically saying that every order $R$ which is wellorder, i.e. an order such that any satisfied property $P$ has a minimal element that satisfies it, is a total order.

Comment: "In second-order logic we can start to state that relations between relations hold for certain relations or for all the possible relations, something which cannot be done in first-order logic." w-w-...what? XD Pardon my ignorance; is there a good/easy example of what you mean by this?

Comment: @user525966 sure, if you want I can add the example to the answer (trying to stay the as informal as possible).

Comment: @user525966 done, does the the edit2 satisfy you?

Comment: Yes, thank you. In practice do people need to get into second order logic as much? It seems a lot more involved

Comment: @user525966 well I would say no but that is because people usually do mathematics in a set theory. In this way they can represent properties and relations as sets, which becomes object of the theory, and so they can do everything using just a first-order logic. But if you are interested in studying relations (or even relations between relations and so on) outside of a theory of this kind you need an second (or even higher order logic).

Comment: So it seems like as we increase the "order" to order n, we just start talking about ways to fiddle with the rules/quantifications of the "n-1"th order logic?

Comment: @user525966 Sort of.