# What sort of Mathematical logic knowledge would help gain better understanding of Mathematics?

Tags: soft-question

There is a definition of Mathematical logic [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993596/what-is-mathematical-logic).

I have studied *Jech introduction to Set theory* till chapter 9. I have understood definitions and have done proofs. To be quite frank, I did not feel like I am gaining better understanding of logic behind Mathematics.

This means being able to construct complex proofs or proof techniques or anything related to proof construction. Most Mathematics done in books use straightforward logic and proof techniques.

> Is there any branch of Math regarding in depth explanation of quantifier manipulation, proof techniques and more? What does make a technique tick?

In addition, the Jech book did not clarify some concepts used in the book very well like limit definition in ordinals.
I know in courses like Topology you will gain better understanding of proof techniques, that's true. But this only happens in proving stuff like Uhryson lemma, Tikhonov theorem and .... But there is no clear explanation of the proof technique used to proof such famous theorems. Like construction a sequence on $[0,1]$ interval and so on.

What I am looking for is not a proof technique book like George Polya's but something more in depth scrutinizing things told above or giving better explanations about techniques used.

---

I did my best to ask the question in such way that you guys can provide better answers. If anything is not clear please let me know so I can revise it instead of down-voting and putting this in off-topic section.

Comment: Proof techniques is literally what math is all about,  that's like asking for all of math in one book.